# Scoverage generates no reports for project

Tags: scala, gradle, gradle-plugin, scoverage

Trying to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/scoverage/gradle-scoverage). My `build.gradle` looks like this (with some trimming):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.scoverage:gradle-scoverage:1.0.9'
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'scala'
    apply plugin: 'scoverage'

    dependencies {
        compile('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6')
        scoverage 'org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11:1.0.4', 'org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11:1.0.4'
    }
}

project(':davinci-server') {
    // SNIP
}
```

When I run `./gradlew testScoverage` though things start to look suspicious.

```
:davinci-server:compileScoverageJava UP-TO-DATE
:davinci-server:compileScoverageScala
:davinci-server:processScoverageResources UP-TO-DATE
:davinci-server:scoverageClasses
:davinci-server:compileTestScoverageJava UP-TO-DATE
:davinci-server:compileTestScoverageScala UP-TO-DATE
:davinci-server:processTestScoverageResources UP-TO-DATE
:davinci-server:testScoverageClasses UP-TO-DATE
:davinci-server:testScoverage UP-TO-DATE
```

Since this is the first time I've run anything scoverage related, I wouldn't expect so many tasks to be `UP-TO-DATE`.

The `scoverageClasses` task seems to have worked just fine, and it has put several `.class` files in `davinci-server/build/classes/scoverage`. No reports appear to be generated, and `./gradlew reportScoverage` just gets skipped because `task onlyIf is false`.

So I run `./gradlew --debug testScoverage` and at first I don't see any hints. Maybe you'll see something interesting in this section, but I didn't:

```
14:42:31.709 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :davinci-server:testScoverageClasses (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 40,5,main]) started.
14:42:31.709 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :davinci-server:testScoverageClasses
14:42:31.709 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':davinci-server:testScoverageClasses'
14:42:31.709 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter] Skipping task ':davinci-server:testScoverageClasses' as it has no actions.
14:42:31.709 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':davinci-server:testScoverageClasses'
14:42:31.709 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :davinci-server:testScoverageClasses UP-TO-DATE
14:42:31.709 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :davinci-server:testScoverageClasses (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 40,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
14:42:31.710 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :davinci-server:testScoverage (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 40,5,main]) started.
14:42:31.710 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :davinci-server:testScoverage
14:42:31.710 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':davinci-server:testScoverage'
14:42:31.710 [DEBUG] [org.scoverage.ScoverageExtension] classpath, testSourceSet.runtimeClasspath: file collection
14:42:31.710 [DEBUG] [org.scoverage.ScoverageExtension] testClassesDir, testSourceSet.output.classesDir: /Users/coryklein/domo/davinci/davinci-server/build/classes/testScoverage
14:42:31.710 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':davinci-server:testScoverage' is up-to-date
14:42:31.710 [DEBUG] [org.scoverage.ScoverageExtension] testClassesDir, testSourceSet.output.classesDir: /Users/coryklein/domo/davinci/davinci-server/build/classes/testScoverage
14:42:31.712 [DEBUG] [org.scoverage.ScoverageExtension] classpath, testSourceSet.runtimeClasspath: file collection
// SNIP
14:42:31.967 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':davinci-server:testScoverage' as it is up-to-date (took 0.257 secs).
14:42:31.967 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':davinci-server:testScoverage'
14:42:31.967 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :davinci-server:testScoverage UP-TO-DATE
14:42:31.967 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :davinci-server:testScoverage (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 40,5,main]) completed. Took 0.257 secs.
```

However, looking elsewhere in the debug output, I did find this gem:

```
14:42:31.116 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':davinci-server:compileScoverageJava'
14:42:31.116 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory '/Users/coryklein/domo/davinci/davinci-server/src/scoverage/java', not found
14:42:31.116 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory '/Users/coryklein/domo/davinci/davinci-server/src/main/java', not found
14:42:31.116 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':davinci-server:compileScoverageJava' as it has no source files.
14:42:31.116 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':davinci-server:compileScoverageJava'
```

It looks like `compileScoverageJava` is being skipped because it can't find any source files in `davinci-server/src/scoverage/scala`, but I can't figure out for the life of me why it's looking there anyway: my source code is in `davinci-server/src/main/scala` and gradle knows it, dammit!

I've tried compiling my own version of the `gradle-scoverage` plugin that is littered with `logger.debug` statements left and right, but can't find where the `src/scoverage` path is coming from or any other indication as to why scoverage isn't working.

Does anybody have any idea where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: Kust to note, compileScoverageJava is skipped because you don't have a java classes under src/main/java, but not scala, so it seems to be ok. Your scala classes will be tested by compileScoverageScala, I think. Have you tryied to modify your scala sources to make them build again?